# Emberjs JSON not rendering

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I am trying to figure out Ember.js. I must be missing a step here because I am not getting my JSON output to the template. It worked when I put the JSON directly in the route code but I can't seem to output it from an HTTP request. I get an error (this is just a clip of it) -

Error while processing route: movies
console.error()vendor.js (line 17062)
logError()vendor.js (line 52719)
error = Object { readyState=4, responseText="[\n {\n show_title: "Donn... runtime: "96 min"\n }\n]", status=200, more...}
initialMessage = "Error while processing route: movies"

the route

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.IndieAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    host: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/938840e95be0a7433e40/raw/8dc899ba72ae0c4c3c89d3fed6cd5b5798f4a8da/movies.json'
});

export default Ember.store = DS.Store.create({
   adapter: 'Indie.IndieAdapter'
});

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
   return this.store.find('movies');
  }
});
```

the model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
   show_title: DS.attr('string'),
   release_year: DS.attr('string'),
   rating: DS.attr('string'),
   director: DS.attr('string'),
   summary: DS.attr('string'),
   poster: DS.attr('string'),
   runtime: DS.attr('string')
});
```

template

```
<h1>Welcome to the Movies page</h1>
{{#each}}
<h2>{{show_title}}</h2>
{{release_year}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please build a jsbin ? You would get answer faster !

Comment: I was going to but because of the imports I get a lot of errors. I am using Ember-CLI. I know it must be something simple. I am pretty sure it is this block of code that probably only needs a line or two that I can;t figure out. export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
   return this.store.find('movies');
  }
});

Comment: did you check the rest call which ember-data is sending?